# Trabalhando com dados hierárquicos

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando um sistema onde os administradores irão definir as permissões dos usuários. Como quero fazer de uma forma organizada e bem detalhada, pensei em criar as permissões por grupos, hierarquicamente, dessa forma:

> - Item 1
>
>   - Cadastrar
>   - Alterar
>   - Deletar
> - Item 2
>
>   - Mesma coisa do Item 1
>
>     - Porém poderá conter mais nós
>
>       - E ainda mais se for necessário :)
> - Item 3

Ok, a lógica está criada e o banco de dados também, porém como tratar isso no php?

Não gostaria de ter que limitar a quantidade de nós, então teria que ser uma forma dinâmica de consultar. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Respondi sem comentar a parte dos grupos de usuários, como você escreveu que a lógica e o banco de dados já esta definido então acho que essa parte de agrupar os usuários e dar os mesmos acessos para este grupo já esteja solucionado, caso não me avise que edito meu post complementando essa parte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tenho uma implementação que vai de encontro com o que você deseja, mas, para explicar vou por partes:

O resultado final ficaria assim: (em vermelho não tem permissão em verde com permissão)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bem você disse que a parte do banco de dados esta pronta, mas não mostrou então vou mostrar como eu ajeitei lá no banco de dados.

```
    CREATE TABLE `tab_modulo` (
  `mod_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'PK',
  `mod_tipo` varchar(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'MENU -> MENU DO SISTEMA\nMENU-SUB -> SUB-MENU DO SISTEMA\nMODULO -> MODULO DO SISTEMA\nMODULOUP -> MODULO QUE CONTEM NIVEIS DE ACESSO\nNIVELUP -> NIVEL DE CESSO DENTRO DE UM MODULO',
  `mod_nome` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'tag para visualização no html',
  `mod_apelido` varchar(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Nome do Menu/Sub-Menu, nome que aparece na interface permissões etc.',
  `mod_ref` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Usado para referenciar os sub-menus a qual menu(mod_id) ele pertence',
  `mod_atalho` char(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'tecla de atalho',
  `mod_ordem` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0 para ficar em cima na ordenacao e valores positivos irão fazer descer o item na ordenacao',
  PRIMARY KEY (`mod_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=116 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Modulos e Menus do sistema';
```

Entendendo o conceito:

- MENU - parte que aparece sem passar o mouse ( esta em cinza na imagem)
- SUB-MENU - Parte onde os modulos são agrupados ( sub-titulo se preferir )
- MODULO - A pagina que será dado o acesso ( tem o checkbox há frente )
- MODULO UP e NIVEL UP - Permissões especiais dentro de um modulo ( aparece como se fosse um sub-item de um modulo )

  ```
      mysql> select * from tab_modulo limit 4;
  +--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------+-----------+
  | mod_id | mod_tipo | mod_nome                                                                              | mod_apelido    | mod_ref | mod_atalho | mod_ordem |
  +--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------+-----------+
  |      1 | MENU-SUB | <b>Carta Frete</b>                                                                    | Carta Frete    |      42 | c          |         4 |
  |      2 | MENU     | <b>Financeiro</b>                                                                     | Financeiro     |       0 | f          |         1 |
  |      4 | MENU     | <b>Administrador</b>                                                                  | Administrador  |       0 | a          |         6 |
  |      5 | MODULO   | <a href="javascript:loadContent('#conteudo','consultaFrete.php');">Consulta Carta</a> | Consulta Carta |       1 | c          |         0 |
  +--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------+-----------+
  ```

Deixei um atributo com marcações de *TAG* para quando o php for colocar na pagina o menu já ficar certinho, e o um atributo com a descrição sem tag para gerar a lista de permissões para eu ficar marcando/desmarcando as permissões.

no php fiz uma funcao para gerar o menu assim:

```
    private function construirMenuPermissoes(){
    for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($this->objeto); $i++) {   
        if($this->objeto[$i]->mod_tipo == 'MENU'){    //ENTÃO ELE É UM MENU PRINCIPAL
            $this->menus[] = $this->objeto[$i];                
            $mod_id = $this->objeto[$i]->mod_id;
            $mod_apelido = $this->objeto[$i]->mod_apelido;             
            $mod_nome = $this->objeto[$i]->mod_nome;
            $menu = "<div id='p$mod_id' mod_id='$mod_id' class='div-menu'><ul style='width: 180px;'>".
                   // "<li id='".$mod_apelido."'>".
                        "<legend class='ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all legend'>$mod_nome</legend>?".
                        "<ul id='browser' class='treeview ".$mod_apelido."' style='margin-top: -10px;'>"; //cria o menu no nivel principal
            $itens = "";
            $itens = $itens.$this->getSubNiveis2($mod_id);                
            echo $menu.$itens."</ul></ul></div>";
        }
    } 
}

private function getSubNiveis2($mod_id){ //FUNCAO RECURSIVA USADA NO PERMISSOES.PHP
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($this->objeto); $i++) {      
        $mod_apelido = $this->objeto[$i]->mod_apelido;            
        $mod_ref = $this->objeto[$i]->mod_ref;
        $mod_tipo = $this->objeto[$i]->mod_tipo;   
        $id = $this->objeto[$i]->mod_id;
        if( $mod_ref == $mod_id){
            if($mod_tipo == 'MENU-SUB'){
                $menu = @$menu."<li id='p".$id."' mod_id='$id' ><b>".$mod_apelido."</b><ul>";
                $menu = @$menu.$this->getSubNiveis2($id)."</ul>"; //MOD_ID DO ARRAY NAO DO PARAMETRO
            }               
            else if($mod_tipo == 'MODULOUP'){                                // ACESSO ELEVADO DENTRO DE UM MODULO
                $menu = @$menu."<li id='p".$id."' style='padding-bottom: 6px; font: bold 8pt Arial;'><b>".$mod_apelido.
                        "<input class='".$id."' type='checkbox' style='float: right; cursor: pointer;'/>".
                        "</b><ul>";
                $menu = @$menu.$this->getSubNiveis2($id)."</ul>"; //MOD_ID DO ARRAY NAO DO PARAMETRO
            }
            else{                    
                $menu = @$menu."<li id='p".$id.
                        "' style='padding-bottom: 6px; font: bold 8pt Arial;'>".$mod_apelido.
                        "<input class='".$id."' mod_ref='" . $mod_ref . "'
                            type='checkbox' style='float: right; cursor: pointer;'/>"."</li>";
            }
        }
    }
    return $menu;
}
```

Onde $this->objeto é o array de todos os módulos que tenho registrado no banco de dados. Espero que tenha lhe ajudado, duvidas a disposição.

Comment: Nesse caso `NIVELUP` seria o último nível possível certo?! (O equivalente a `Travar Lançamentos` da segundo coluna). A lógica é um pouco parecida, porém preciso dar espaços para mais nós se precisar, vou precisar reaproveitar esse código para um sistema de categorias de uma loja que vai ter muito mais nós, então já quero desenvolve-lo da melhor maneira possível. Obrigado pelas informações, só vou aguardar um pouco mais antes de fechar :)

Comment: @DiegoMachado não existe ultimo nivel, esse NIVELUP é para por exemplo uma pessoa tem acesso a um modulo, mas dentro desse modulo por exemplo um pode gravar outro somente visualizar, nada impede você de criar outros MENU-SUB, quantas vezes forem necessários

Comment: O Segredo é fazer o atributo mod_ref receber o mod_id do nó a cima, assim você pode fazer quantos sub-menu forem necessários

Comment: Entendi, em minha tabela tenho o campo `parent_id` que equivale ao `mod_ref`. Vou terminar meu código e aplicar algumas ideias que tirei do seu. Assim que finalizar posto o resultado.

Comment: ok, só para completar o que foi dito segue o link de exemplo http://i.imgur.com/jGsfkgQ.png

Comment: Agora está tudo ok! Foi bem mais simples que pensei, rs.. Mas programação é assim, tem coisas fáceis que as vezes não entra na cabeça :) Abraços! edit: A gratificação só da pra conceder daqui uma hora não sei pq. Só aguardar

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Diego, cara creio que a melhor forma pra você fazer isto é separar os usuários por status que seriam nada mais que agrupamentos de permissões.

Desta maneira você teria dois fluxos no seu sistema, uma tela em que o Administrador ia criar status, exemplo (Administrador, Editor, Operador) e outra tela em que o Administrador do sistema iria vincular permissões a cada status por exemplo: Administradores possuem controle total, Editores podem editar e criar, Operadores pode apenas visualizar.

Vale ressaltar que o as permissões não poderiam ser criadas a partir do painel, uma vez que não teria como você prever no script do seu sistema uma permissão que não exista.

Valeu, espero ter ajudado.
Abraço.

Comment: Essa foi minha primeira ideia na verdade, mas grupos não seriam eficientes nesse caso, senão eu teria que criar muitos grupos. Gostaria de dar permissão individual e como o sistema terá vários campos, precisará dessa árvore. Eu vou utilizar essa lógica também em um projeto paralelo de uma loja virtual para fazer as categorias do produto, então de qualquer maneira eu preciso dessa árvore. Mas obrigado pela resposta.